# Sort list of lists using custom compare function python

Tags: python, sorting

I was trying to sort list of lists in python but it doesn't seem to work.

```
def get(l):
        return l[1]

def com(x,y):
        return len(x) < len(y)

x = [['jis','1,2334'],['hshshau','123'],['sjuaj','3214']]
x.sort(cmp=com,key=get)
```

Output

```
[['jis', '1,2334'], ['hshshau', '123'], ['sjuaj', '3214']]
```

How to achieve list in increasing order of 2nd element ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `cmp` here just use a `key` :

```
>>> x = [['jis','1,2334'],['hshshau','123'],['sjuaj','3214']]
>>> 
>>> x.sort(key=lambda x:len(x[1]))
>>> x
[['hshshau', '123'], ['sjuaj', '3214'], ['jis', '1,2334']]
>>>
```

And you need to know that `sort` function will sort the list elements based on the `key` and here your key doesn't consider the length of your elements. you just sorting based on second element and `sort` will sort your list based on second element lexicographicaly!

For more information about python `sort` function read https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted

Answer (score 1):

Like @Kasra said you do not need to use the `cmp` parameter, you can just use the key , also if you want to consider the second element as integers (numbers) you can replace',' with '' (Assuming only `,` will come in that) (empty string) and then convert to int and use, so that numbers of same length are also sorted correctly.

Example -

```
>>> x = [['jis','1,2334'],['hshshau','123'],['sjuaj','3214'],['nbhd','1,841']]
>>> x.sort(key = lambda x: int(x[1].replace(',','')))
>>> x
[['hshshau', '123'], ['nbhd', '1,841'], ['sjuaj', '3214'], ['jis', '1,2334']]
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) for `cmp` argument -

> cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (iterable elements) which should return a negative, zero or positive number

As you can see above, cmp function needs to return 0 if both are equal, positive number if the first is greater and negative number if the first is less than the second argument.

But in your case you are returning a boolean value, causing the issue.